# Is it a good idea to add script to the website via GTM?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am running a WordPress website for a bigger company. We have tech team for the website and Marketing team for the marketing. My problem is our marketing team is keep adding some javascript to the website using gtm. Also they use document.write to add the javascript. In my opinion this is a bad practice. But I need to clarify if this is something we should avoid or keep doing? Will this be a problem for the website performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding any 3rd-party scripts, like Google Analytics, Google Tag Manager, Hotjar, Intercom, or anything similar, will have *some* performance impact on your site. That said, these scripts are often required for various marketing, A/B split testing, chat widgets, error monitoring, and other reasons. So it's a trade-off.

Your website *could* see a performance improvement without these 3rd-party scripts, but they're probably necessary for business reasons, and probably help solve other issues.

Regarding Google Tag Manager specifically - it allows your marketing team to manage (add, update, remove) 3rd-party scripts (tags) on their own - instead of requiring the tech team to add, update, and remove various tags. One of the most common uses for Google Tag Manager is to add the Google Analytics tracking code to a site, but this is just one of many uses.

As an example, using Google Tag Manager the marketing team can add the Google Analytics tracking code, and set up a custom event to track clicks on `.pdf` files and push this event to Google Analytics. Without Google Tag Manager the marketing team would need to ask the tech team to add the Google Analytics tracking code, and manually add JS code to track an event on the site - requiring the tech team to do some work and deploy the update.

Personally, I use Google Tag Manager even though I'm a developer myself. It makes adding tags and tracking events much easier than writing the code manually. For example, I can easily setup events to track `.pdf` clicks, form submissions (on embedded forms form Hubspot), and external link clicks. These were all set up through Google Tag Manager without having to write any custom JS tracking events, or deploying an update to our site. Even better, Google Tag Manager tracks changes, and allows me to test the changes before making them official - both tasks which would be more difficult to do if not using Google Tag Manager.

So in most cases, you probably want to keep using Google Tag Manager.

***That said***, it's a great idea to keep an eye on the tags being added through Google Tag Manager, so your concerns are valid. Too many tags and your site will have a decrease in performance. Removing tags and other events which are no longer needed will keep your site performing as well as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Adding JavaScript to a web page is the point of Google Tag Manager, so it is not as such a bad practice (after all GTM is just a piece of Javascript itself).

However GTM does barely discern between good and bad JavaScript (it won't allow gross syntax errors, but it will not check performance), so GTM makes it really easy to shoot into one's own foot. It allows laypersons to add Javascript, and laypersons are not necessarily good at judging the performance impact of Javascript.

Since you run Wordpress, GTM is in an way like adding an extension to Wordpress. Basically anybody can do it, but not a lot of people are able to judge if the extension is secure and performant.

GTM offers templates for the more important tags (and a curated version of Javascript to develop custom templates), so the best practice would be to disallow custom HTML and rely on templates (you can specifically whitelist/blacklist certain tags and variables).

If you need to allow custom HTML you should have some sort of workflow, where marketing people do not have publish rights, but need to have their JS looked over by a developer (GTM 360 offers some basic workflow tools, I don't think they are available in the free version).

Basically, adding third party Javascript to a site always opens you up to a certain risk, both with respect to performance and security. That's true no matter if it is added via GTM or by any other means. If you feel that your marketing team is not aware of all implications (as their use of document.write seems to suggest), then you should not necessarily abandon GTM, but restrict access/permissions and install some sort of oversight (which of course removes much of the convenience from having GTM).